# Does Dark One's Blessing Stack with itself?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock

In dnd 5e I know that the temporary hp from two different sources doesn't stack. What if I killed two enemies in a combat? Do I get 2x(warlock level+cha bonus)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Temporary Hit Points don't stack, period.

From the *Temporary Hit Points* section on page 197 of the PHB:

> [...] they can’t be added together. If you have temporary hit points and receive more of them, you decide whether to keep the ones you have or to gain the new ones.

Comment: Is that also true if the enemies are killed at the same time (i.e. in the same AoE-attack)? I then do not have temporary hit points, but get multiple HP at the same time...

Comment: @arc_lupus Generally events are not simultaneous - if the order of resolution matters, the DM will decide the order.  An optional rule in XGtE says the order can go to the player whose turn it is.  So if your warlock killed > 1 opponent with an AoE on your turn, either the warlock of the DM decides who actually dies first and who came just after.